# I want to design a grid with n-number of dimensions ,solution for two dimension is available but i want n-dimensions in Numpy?

Tags: python, numpy, datadesign

I need to generate a grid for an array with a general/variable number of dimensions. In the 2D case, I know I can use mgrid:

## Some 2D data

```
N = 1000
x = np.random.uniform(0., 1., N)
y = np.random.uniform(10., 100., N)
xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax = x.min(), x.max(), y.min(), y.max()
```

## Obtain 2D grid

```
xy_grid = np.mgrid[xmin:xmax:10j, ymin:ymax:10j]
```

How can I scale this approach when the number of dimensions is variable? Ie: my data could be (x, y) or (x, y, z) or (x, y, z, q), etc.

The naive approach of:

## Md_data.shape = (M, N), for M dimensions

```
dmin, dmax = np.amin(Md_data, axis=1), np.amax(Md_data, axis=1)
Md_grid = np.mgrid[dmin:dmax:10j]
```

does not work

Answer (score 0):

`meshgrid` as a function lets us use '*' unpacking:

```
In [412]: dmin,dmax=np.array([1,2,3]), np.array([5,6,7])
In [423]: arr = np.linspace(dmin,dmax,5)
In [424]: arr
Out[424]: 
array([[1., 2., 3.],
       [2., 3., 4.],
       [3., 4., 5.],
       [4., 5., 6.],
       [5., 6., 7.]])
```

I'm using `sparse` for a more compact display.

```
In [425]: atup = np.meshgrid(*arr.T,indexing='ij',sparse=True)
In [426]: atup
Out[426]: 
[array([[[1.]],
 
        [[2.]],
 
        [[3.]],
 
        [[4.]],
 
        [[5.]]]),
 array([[[2.],
         [3.],
         [4.],
         [5.],
         [6.]]]),
 array([[[3., 4., 5., 6., 7.]]])]
```

This `ogrid` does the same thing:

```
np.ogrid[1:5:5j,2:6:5j,3:7:5j]
```

Come to think of it, so is

```
np.ix_(arr[:,0],arr[:,1],arr[:,2])
```

though it doesn't have the `nonsparse` alternative.